# Different volume levels do not work while using Web Audio API

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, html5-audio, web-audio-api

```
public useAudio(base64EncodedAudio: any, loop: boolean, volume: number) {
    let _this = this;
    let audioFromString = this.base64ToBuffer(base64EncodedAudio);
    this._context.decodeAudioData(audioFromString, function (buffer) {
        _this.audioBuffer = buffer;
        _this.PlaySound(loop, volume);
    }, function (error) {
        TelemetryClient.error(EventType.BASE64_DECODE_ERROR, "Error decoding sound string");
    });

}

private PlaySound(loop: boolean, volume: number) {
    this._source = this._context.createBufferSource();

    let gainNode = this._context.createGain();
    gainNode.gain.value = +(volume / 100).toFixed(2);
    gainNode.connect(this._context.destination);

    this._source.buffer = this._audioBuffer;
    this._source.loop = loop;
    this._source.connect(gainNode);
    this._source.start(0);
}
```

gainNode.gain.value doesn't seem to work properly. Value 1 and 0.15 plays the sound at the full volume.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Please inform us which exact version of the MS Edge browser you are using for making this test? I agree with the suggestion given by @chrisguttandin. Did you try to run this code on any other machine to check for the result? If not, you can have a check and let us know about the results may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: No idea if it's related, but you are setting a string as value.

Answer (score 0):

The [gain `AudioParam`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-gainnode-gain) can handle very large values but if you want to lower the volume its value has to be somewhere in between 0 and 1. When the value is 0 no sound will be audible and a value of 1 will actually bypass the `GainNode`. Any larger value will amplify the sound. But depending on the browser and operating system you may not hear that since there might be a limiter in place before the sound hits your speakers.

Comment: I apologize for the wrong details in the question. Value 1 and 0.15 doesn't seem to produce any difference. Hence I'm saying the volume is not working correctly. 
Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No worries. But unfortunately I don't know an easy fix in that case. I would have done some things differently and your code does at least have one bug (`_this.audioBuffer` vs `this._audioBuffer`). But nothing seems to be wrong with the `GainNode`.

Comment: I highly recommend creating a snippet somewhere that demonstrates the issue.  That way its a nice self-contained example where people can play with it to see what's going on.